# Require a model to have another model? Basically, a model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rails-models

What I mean is, is it possible in Rails to require at least one instance of a model in a relationship?

For example, in my `discussion.rb` I have:

```
has_many :posts
```

And in my `post.rb`:

```
belongs_to :discussion
```

How can I make it that in order to create a discussion you need to have at least one Post? I was not sure how to search for this question, so I apologize if it's already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post record will need a discussion_id foreign key in order to be associated with a discussion. The discussion can't be created (and given an id) until the post is created. It's a catch-22.

You'll have to introduce something else, like a "complete" boolean on the discussion model that only gets flipped true after a post is created.

Answer (score 1):

[validates_presence_of](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000083) will do the trick I think.